# setBackgroundColor is always turn purple

Tags: java, android

Why when I change the background color through `setBackgroundColor(R.id.bg_primary)` always turns purple?

**My color resource is**

```
<color name="bg_primary">#FFFF0000</color>
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: I don't know about Android but I can tell you that ```#FFFF0000``` is not a valid color hex because it has 8 digits and ```#FFFF00``` is yellow.

Comment: 8 digits is for AARRGGBB

Comment: Alpha Red Green Blue

Comment: when the alpha value is 100% try to remove it and see if it's working without the alpha value

Comment: yes i know but it still turn to purple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think when you use `setBackgroundColor(R.id.bg_primary)` must set color code to parameter but you send color id for parameter .

test this . maybe it work : `setBackgroundResource(R.id.bg_primary);`

Answer (score 0):

Try `setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bg_primary))`